# Detect upload speed bandwidth using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

Is there a way of detecting upload speed using jquery/javascript. For detecting download speed we make use of pseudostreaming where we calculate the total time taken in receiving the response.

On similar ground can we detect upload speed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phillip Tellis did a great presentation on it at JSconf.EU and also wrote this article about it:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/14/analyzing-network-characteristics-using-javascript-and-the-dom-part-1/